# Moving image moves the whole Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating an app on Tkinter that requires to drag and drop images. The problem is that when the image is moved, the whole canvas is moved. Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

[image]
[image]

**CODE**

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
mycanvas = Canvas(root, bg = 'red')
mycanvas.pack()

def cargarimg(archivo): # Se carga imagen
        ruta = os.path.join('img', archivo)
        imagen = PhotoImage(file = ruta)
        return imagen

photo = cargarimg("Res.png")

a = mycanvas.create_image(100, 100, image = photo)

def drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)

mycanvas.tag_bind(a, '<Button-1>', drag_start)
mycanvas.tag_bind(a, '<B1-Motion>', drag_motion)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `event.widget` is the canvas, not the image item `a`.

You need to use canvas's method `move()` or `moveto()` to move the image item instead.  Below is updated `drag_motion()` using `move()`:

```
def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    dx, dy = event.x-widget.startX, event.y-widget.startY
    event.widget.move(a, dx, dy)
    widget.startX, widget.startY = event.x, event.y
```